# Meaning of the word "talk"

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what is the exact meaning of the word "talk" in the following sentence?

> Elixir Radar. A weekly email with blog posts, latest libraries, talks, events and job opportunities.

I looked through these definitions, but I am not sure which one is relevant. Perhaps - lecture? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk

Comment: What is the source of the sentence? Can you link it?

Comment: Sure, but it's just a list of links )) not very helpful https://github.com/vredniy/awesome-newsletters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A talk in this case is, as you say, an informal address or lecture.

> a thirty-minute illustrated talk

Synonyms: lecture, speech, address, discourse, oration, presentation, report, sermon, disquisition, dissertation, symposium; informal spiel

> a firefighter giving a talk on her personal experiences